# Rails 4 + -jquery-datatable + ajax-datatable - Erro 406 Http e ActionController::UnknownFormat format json

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rails4

Estava estudando rails e seguindo o tutorial https://github.com/antillas21/ajax-datatables-rails.

OS passos do tutorial eram os seguintes, criar uma datatable que realizaria uma requisiçao via json, ao controller que responderia com os dados e a data table seria populada.

No momento do teste recebi o seguinte erro do servidor: 406 Not Acceptable, e detalhando o erro pelo chrome na aba network, é exibido o erro abaixo:

## ActionController::UnknownFormat at /categories.json%20

> ActionController::UnknownFormat

### app/controllers/categories_controller.rb, line 8

``` ruby
    3     before_action :set_category, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]
    4
    5     # GET /categories
    6     # GET /categories.json
    7     def index

> 8       respond_to do |format|
>       9         format.html
>      10         format.json { render json: CategoryDatatable.new(view_context)}
>      11       end
>      12      end
>      13
>   ```

Pesquisei porém não consegui chegar ou encontrar uma solução.

Segue abaixo passo a passo do código caso alguem possa me ajudar ficarei agradecido:

View:

[image: index.html.erb]

Coffe: Responsavel por atualizar a datatable quando chamada pela view
[image: categories.js.coffe]

Controller - método index:
[image: categories_controller.rb]

Erro browser : Aba Network:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Erro browser detalhado:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Ou seja o servidor pelo que entendi não aceita a chamada via json, porém não descobri como faze-lo aceitar. Os tutoriais ou erros parecidos que encontrei estão da mesma forma e segundo os autores funcionam.

Se eu faço a requisição direto no browser http://localhost:3000/categories.json é exibido o arquivo sem problemas:
**{"draw":0,"recordsTotal":3,"recordsFiltered":3,"data":[[1,"Teste1","Erro","Sim"],[2,"Teste2","Melhoria","Sim"],[4,"Teste3","Erro Usuario","Não"]]}**

Se alguem puder me ajudar ficarei agradecido.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O erro está indicando que o rails não reconhece o formato utilizado na requisição.

Na view o valor do atributo `data-source` possui um espaço após a url, portanto a requisição realizada pelo DataTable é [http://localhost:3000/categories.json<kbd>espaço</kbd>](http://localhost:3000/categories.json%20) e o rails está tentando renderizar o formato .json<kbd>espaço</kbd>

Basta você remover o <kbd>espaço</kbd> ao final do valor do `data-source`.

Comment: Vlw amigo muito obrigado...nem acredito nisso..um espaço... e achando que o erro era coisa de outro mundo...